How do I reference a global in a WinDbg dx expression?
In WinDbg, I have a global variable:
> x /v paex_sine!KSPROPSETID_RTAudio
prv global 00007ff6`436598a8   10 paex_sine!KSPROPSETID_RtAudio = {A855A48C-2F78-4729-9051-1968746B9EEF}

I can use it with ? and ??:
> ? paex_sine!KSPROPSETID_RTAudio
Evaluate expression: 140695669414056 = 00007ff6`436598a8
> ?? paex_sine!KSPROPSETID_RTAudio
struct _GUID
 {a855a48c-2f78-4729-9051-1968746b9eef}
   +0x000 Data1            : 0xa855a48c
   +0x004 Data2            : 0x2f78
   +0x006 Data3            : 0x4729
   +0x008 Data4            : [8]  "???"

But as soon as I try to use it with dx, I get this error:
> dx paex_sine!KSPROPSETID_RTAudio
Error: Unable to bind name 'KSPROPSETID_RTAudio'

Is there any way to reference global variables in dx? My ultimate goal is to use it as part of a conditional breakpoint (bp /w).

source
:\>dir /b
guid.cpp

:\>type guid.cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
GUID MyFoo = { 0XA855A48C,0X2F78,0X4729, {0X90,0x51,0X19,0X68,0X74,0X6B,0X9E,0XEF} };
int main(){
        printf("MyFoo.Data1 = %0x\n" , MyFoo.Data1);
}

compiled and executed
:\>cl /Zi /WX /nologo /analyze /Ox guid.cpp /link /release
guid.cpp

:\>guid.exe
MyFoo.Data1 = a855a48c

windbg
:\>cdb -c "x /v guid!MyFoo;? guid!MyFoo; ?? guid!MyFoo;dx guid!MyFoo";q guid.exe

Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.19041.685 AMD64

ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak+0x30:
00007ffc`a4d60750 cc              int     3

0:000> cdb: Reading initial command 'x /v guid!MyFoo;? guid!MyFoo; ?? guid!MyFoo;dx guid!MyFoo;q'

prv global 00007ff6`3f31d000   10 guid!MyFoo = {A855A48C-2F78-4729-9051-1968746B9EEF}

Evaluate expression: 140695598911488 = 00007ff6`3f31d000

struct _GUID
 {a855a48c-2f78-4729-9051-1968746b9eef}
   +0x000 Data1            : 0xa855a48c
   +0x004 Data2            : 0x2f78
   +0x006 Data3            : 0x4729
   +0x008 Data4            : [8]  "???"
   
guid!MyFoo       : {A855A48C-2F78-4729-9051-1968746B9EEF} [Type: _GUID]
    [<Raw View>]     [Type: _GUID]
quit:
:\>

i can even drill down to the Data4[*] unsigned chars
0:000> dx  -r9 -nv guid!MyFoo
guid!MyFoo                 : {A855A48C-2F78-4729-9051-1968746B9EEF} [Type: _GUID]
    [+0x000] Data1            : 0xa855a48c [Type: unsigned long]
    [+0x004] Data2            : 0x2f78 [Type: unsigned short]
    [+0x006] Data3            : 0x4729 [Type: unsigned short]
    [+0x008] Data4            [Type: unsigned char [8]]
        [0]              : 0x90 [Type: unsigned char]
        [1]              : 0x51 [Type: unsigned char]
        [2]              : 0x19 [Type: unsigned char]
        [3]              : 0x68 [Type: unsigned char]
        [4]              : 0x74 [Type: unsigned char]
        [5]              : 0x6b [Type: unsigned char]
        [6]              : 0x9e [Type: unsigned char]
        [7]              : 0xef [Type: unsigned char]


Thanks. I tried the same steps and I end up with the same results as yours. Clearly there is something weird going on with that particular program that I'm debugging and I'll need to figure out what makes it different.
